# Unable to place order on checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

In Checkout Page I can't able to Place Order after click Place order it's keep on loading I tried multiple solutions in google but no luck

Change this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('button') ?>
```

to

```
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" class="button btn-checkout" onclick="review.save();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></span></span></button>
```

this script also

```
review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
```

After place order i check consolve it shows

```
allocation size overflow
```

**system.log**

```
2016-06-28T12:14:30+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3937
2016-06-28T12:36:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354
[5] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/index.php:87
</pre>
2016-06-28T12:39:59+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: searchedDesigners  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 97
2016-06-28T12:39:59+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: designerhiddenField  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 100
2016-06-28T12:39:59+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: searchedDesigners  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 97
2016-06-28T12:39:59+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: designerhiddenField  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 100
2016-06-28T12:39:59+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: searchedDesigners  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 97
2016-06-28T12:39:59+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: designerhiddenField  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 100
2016-06-28T12:39:59+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: searchedDesigners  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 97
2016-06-28T12:39:59+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: designerhiddenField  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 100
2016-06-28T12:40:00+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/infinitescroll/infinitescroll.phtml
2016-06-28T12:40:00+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: seller  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/design/frontend/arw_sebian/default/template/catalog/layer/state.phtml on line 35
2016-06-28T12:40:00+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: count  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php on line 157
2016-06-28T12:40:00+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: count  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php on line 157
2016-06-28T12:40:00+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: count  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php on line 157
2016-06-28T12:40:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: searchedDesigners  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 97
2016-06-28T12:40:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: designerhiddenField  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 100
2016-06-28T12:40:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: searchedDesigners  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 97
2016-06-28T12:40:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: designerhiddenField  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 100
2016-06-28T12:40:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: searchedDesigners  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 97
2016-06-28T12:40:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: designerhiddenField  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 100
2016-06-28T12:40:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: searchedDesigners  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 97
2016-06-28T12:40:15+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: designerhiddenField  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/local/ARW/Filter/Block/Product/List.php on line 100
2016-06-28T12:40:16+00:00 CRIT (2): Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/infinitescroll/infinitescroll.phtml
2016-06-28T12:40:16+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: seller  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/design/frontend/arw_sebian/default/template/catalog/layer/state.phtml on line 35
2016-06-28T12:40:16+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: count  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php on line 157
2016-06-28T12:40:16+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: count  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php on line 157
2016-06-28T12:40:16+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: count  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php on line 157
2016-06-28T12:50:44+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3937
2016-06-28T13:06:43+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3937
2016-06-28T13:07:50+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3937
2016-06-28T13:09:38+00:00 ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3937
2016-06-28T13:28:55+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:52
[1] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:768
[2] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:84
[3] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:184
[4] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354
[5] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/app/Mage.php:684
[6] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/domain/index.php:87
</pre>
```

Comment: hy...
please visit this link.
can you mistake this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687125/while-placing-order-from-magento-using-paypal-express-checkout-no-content-is-dis

Comment: i tried with default payment method only

Comment: what does your error_log say?

Comment: Related to checkout no issue

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: check if there are any `echo`, `print_r`, `var_dump` or `die` statement somewhere in your checkout flow. I believe it is breaking the transaction for order save action.